# SVN Version of GRASS and QGIS

Tags: grass-gis, qgis

I have GRASS6.5 SVN installed and wanted to go for SVN installation of Quantum GIS in Ubuntu 11.04. So as instructed in [QGIS Wiki](http://www.qgis.org/wiki/Download#Trunk_3), I added the qgis repository to my `sources.list` file. Now I am able to see **qgis1.7.0svn** version in Synaptic but when I try to install it, **GRASS** is a dependency. How can I install only Quantum GIS and not GRASS from here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're interested in building both packages from source, follow the [Building from Source](http://www.qgis.org/wiki/Building_QGIS_from_Source) instructions on the QGIS Wiki. Going down this route, you can point it at the GRASS libraries you've compiled from SVN, and only rely on apt for the required packages for building the software.

Comment: There's an option in the CMake configuration dialog to disable it. You may need to clear out the `build/` directory you've created and start over, I find the SVN version changes quite rapidly and your build configuration can quickly go stale. You'll also need to install cutting edge versions of QT, the Ubuntu stock libraries (at least as of last month for me) are too old.